# Menu indexpath save UserDefaults swift

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults

I want to save whichever indexpath I last clicked in the menu. He's recording indexpath right now. But if I choose indexpath, he's recording it. If I don't choose, it doesn't. How can I keep the previous record even if I don't select item from the menu?

```
let save11 = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "indexPath")

        let yenindex = save11        
        self.menuView.setSelected(index: yenindex)    
        let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
        userDefaults.removeObject(forKey: "indexPath")

  menuView.didSelectItemAtIndexHandler = {(indexPath: Int) -> Void in   
                var placesdeger: String = ""

      UserDefaults.standard.setValue(indexPath, forKey: "indexPath")

                if indexPath == 0 {
                    let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
                    userDefaults.removeObject(forKey: "indexPath")                    
   UserDefaults.standard.setValue(indexPath, forKey: "indexPath")
                    placesdeger = "Yatak Odası"

            }
                if indexPath == 1 {
                    let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
                    userDefaults.removeObject(forKey: "indexPath")

          UserDefaults.standard.setValue(indexPath, forKey: "indexPath")
                    placesdeger = "Oturma Odası"
                    self.refreshData()

                }
```

Comment: I think you just need to set the default in user defaults of the home screen.

Comment: I don't understand how do I do it? @AbilashBansal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when ever you click on menu remove previous Userdefault value and set new user default value every time.
Put this code and get new index every time and if not selected then old value you will get in Userdefaults

```
       let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
       userDefaults.removeObject(forKey: "index")
       userDefaults.set(i, forKey: "index")
```

**EDIT1** 
 USE THIS IN SOMEWHERE YOU DEFINE CONSTANT ONLY ONCE

```
let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
```

If you are using or any other method i dont know but if you get proper indexpath then this code will work

```
menuView.didSelectItemAtIndexHandler = {(indexPath: Int) -> Void in   
                var placesdeger: String = ""
 userDefaults.removeObject(forKey: "indexPath")

                if indexPath == 0 {
                    let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard

   UserDefaults.standard.setValue(indexPath, forKey: "indexPath")
                    placesdeger = "Yatak Odası"

            }
                if indexPath == 1 {



          UserDefaults.standard.setValue(indexPath, forKey: "indexPath")
                    placesdeger = "Oturma Odası"
                    self.refreshData()

                }
```

Comment: let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
        userDefaults.removeObject(forKey: "i")
        let save11 = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "i)  
        let yenindex = save11      
        self.menuView.setSelected(index: yenindex)
        menuView.didSelectItemAtIndexHandler = {(indexPath: Int) -> Void in                
                UserDefaults.standard.setValue(indexPath, forKey: "i")
                if indexPath == 0 {
                    UserDefaults.standard.setValue(indexPath, forKey: "i")
                } // I did it in the form, but it's not working.

Comment: remove user defaults value in didSelectItemAtIndexHandler before "if" condition

Comment: I changed the code on the subject as you said. It still doesn't work. When I don't pick item, it doesn't record.

Comment: I edit your code in my answer please check @stakabekor

Comment: When I do not select any item from the menu, it does not record again.

Comment: It means userDefaults.removeObject(forKey: "indexPath") this line of code is called , debug and check when its called in your code.

Comment: Index saves when it is selected, but Index does not save when it is not selected. Unfortunately, no Github.

Comment: once it save in userdefault it will be stay in your application until you remove it by yourself or uninstall app

Comment: Ok but when indexPath is not selected, userdefaults does not save the previously registered indexpath.

Comment: That's what I am trying to tell you, Userdefault saves data till the app uninstall or you remove it, Debug your code, You will sure get issue or share your code if possible on Git. Read doc of user defaults

Comment: Or you can save indexpath in static variable, That will also work